# How to use strstr() function to compare content in character arrays in C?

Tags: c, strstr

The purpose of this small program is to compare strings in two separate files (file1.csv and file2.csv), and gives its results to file3.csv. If the strings in file2.csv are found in file1.csv, the program copies the strings in file1.csv to file3.csv.

**Content of file1.csv (with 6 columns):**

```
10000001    text1   text1   text1   text1   text1
10000002    text2   text2   text2   text2   text2
10000003    text3   text3   text3   text3   text3
10000004    text4   text4   text4   text4   text4
10000005    text5   text5   text5   text5   text5
10000006    text6   text6   text6   text6   text6
10000007    text7   text7   text7   text7   text7
10000008    text8   text8   text8   text8   text8
10000009    text9   text9   text9   text9   text9
10000010    text10  text10  text10  text10  text10
10000011    text11  text11  text11  text11  text11
10000012    text12  text12  text12  text12  text12
10000013    text13  text13  text13  text13  text13
10000014    text14  text14  text14  text14  text14
10000015    text15  text15  text15  text15  text15
10000016    text16  text16  text16  text16  text16
10000017    text17  text17  text17  text17  text17
10000018    text18  text18  text18  text18  text18
10000019    text19  text19  text19  text19  text19
10000020    text20  text20  text20  text20  text20
10000021    text21  text21  text21  text21  text21
10000022    text22  text22  text22  text22  text22
10000023    text23  text23  text23  text23  text23
10000024    text24  text24  text24  text24  text24
10000025    text25  text25  text25  text25  text25
```

**Content of file2.csv (only one column):**

```
10000001
10000003
10000004
10000006
10000007
10000008
10000009
10000011
10000012
10000015
10000025
```

**The expected results will be:**

```
10000001    text1   text1   text1   text1   text1
10000003    text3   text3   text3   text3   text3
10000004    text4   text4   text4   text4   text4
10000006    text6   text6   text6   text6   text6
10000007    text7   text7   text7   text7   text7
10000008    text8   text8   text8   text8   text8
10000009    text9   text9   text9   text9   text9
10000011    text11  text11  text11  text11  text11
10000012    text12  text12  text12  text12  text12
10000015    text15  text15  text15  text15  text15
10000025    text25  text25  text25  text25  text25
```

I used the strstr() function to compare the strings but it didn't work, the code are listed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[150][80] = {0};  
    char line2[150][80] = {0};  

    int i = 0, b = 0;

    FILE *file1 = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.csv", "r");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("file3.csv", "w");

    while (fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line[i]) != EOF) {
        i++;
        while (fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2[b]) != EOF) {
            b++;
        }
        if (strstr(line[i],line2[b]))
        fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line[i]);
     }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider what will happen to `file2` after the inner `while` has finished. Files don't automatically rewind when you need them to. A better approach would be to read in all the data to memory in two separate loops, then do the the analysis and writing of a new file.

Comment: "*it didn't work*" Can you use real words, with real meaning, to describe the real problem?

Comment: Always check the result of `fopen();`!

Comment: @unwind reading in ALL data may leed to a memory problem. But at least the pattern-file (file2) should be read into memory beforehand.

Comment: If first column is only numbers, I'd use `atoi` and compare numbers

Comment: If the files are indeed ordered as presented here, I fail to see the need to more than one line buffer and a couple of `unsigned int` variables. Bulk arrays of arrays shouldn't be required for any of this.

Comment: btw: "csv" is abbrev for "comma separated values", your data is separated by whitespace. (leaking abstraction)

Comment: Without confirmation of the ordering I mentioned earlier, [this is sheer speculation](http://pastebin.com/WQNBfqT1), but if the files are indeed ordered as the question data suggests, it will not only work, but likely be fairly quick, as both files are sequentially scanned only *once*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As unwind and other commenters rightly noted, there's no point re-reading `file2.csv` on every `file1.csv` reading iteration. Just read it once and loop through the `line2[]` array then.

Second, you may process the `file1.csv` line-by-line and forget the current line's contents as soon as it's been processed, so making `line[][]` an array is also unnecessary.

Here's your amended code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file, name) \
    if (file == NULL) { \
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", name); \
        return 1; \
    }

int main()
{
    char line[150] = "";  
    char line2[150][80] = {0};

    int b = 0;
    int filterCount = 0;

    FILE *file1 = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file1, "file1.csv");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.csv", "r");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file2, "file2.csv");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("file3.csv", "w");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file3, "file3.csv");

    while (fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2[b]) != EOF) {
        b++;
    }
    filterCount = b;
    while (fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line) != EOF) {
        for (b = 0; b < filterCount; b++) {
            if (strstr(line,line2[b])) {
                fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line);
                break;
            }
        }
     }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

However, your input data seems to be specific enough to make some optimization assumptions. In particular, (a) all files are ordered by the first column value and (b) the second is only a reduced copy of the first (in terms of line index values).

In this case you might want to implement a one-pass processing. Scan both files line by line comparing the index values. Then advance to the next line of the first file on every iteration. As of the second file, only move to the next line when the current line is found in the first file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file, name) \
    if (file == NULL) { \
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", name); \
        return 1; \
    }

int main()
{
    char line1[150] = "";  
    char line2[150] = "";

    FILE *file1 = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file1, "file1.csv");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.csv", "r");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file2, "file2.csv");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("file3.csv", "w");
    CHECK_FILE_OPEN(file3, "file3.csv");

    bool eof1 = fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line1) == EOF;
    bool eof2 = fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2) == EOF;

    while (!eof1 && !eof2) {
        if (strstr(line1, line2)) {
            fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line1);
            eof2 = fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2) == EOF;
        }
        eof1 = fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line1) == EOF;
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note **ALL CAPS** are reserved for system `macros` and `defines` in C (like `FILE`). Nothing stops you from using them, but it is bad practice.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks so much for your answer. I have tested the amended code and it works. In my new version of code (see below), I used for() iteration to scan both files line by line then copying the lines , which correspond to the lines in file2, from file1 to file3 using strstr() . I have also added a new function numberOfLines() to count the numbers of lines in both file1 and file2.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Peter Miehle said, in the case every line in file2 has a match in file1, and that it only matches once; and both files are sorted.

If you don't want to rewind file2.csv, you need to read it in the main loop, and read file1.csv in the sub-loop. The search of the substring have to be in the sub-loop to be performed each time a new line is read. Here is a code that seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[150][80] = {0};
    char line2[150][80] = {0};

    int i = 0, b = 0;

    FILE *file1 = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.csv", "r");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("file3.csv", "w");

    while (fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2[b]) != EOF) {

        while (fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line[i]) != EOF) {

            if (strstr(line[i],line2[b])) {
              printf("\nFound: %s",line2[b]);
              fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line[i]);
              i++;
              break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        b++;
     }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for the very special case that every line in file2 has a match in file1; and that it only matches once; and that both files are sorted.

Comment: You're right, i edited my post, in the case someone miss your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all of you who contributed their time and effort to answer and comment my question. Based on your answers and suggestions, I have just figured it out, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int numberOfLines(char *fn)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fn, "r"); 
    char line[1024]=""; 
    int no = 0;
    if(!file) 
    return 0;
    while(!feof(file)) 
    { 
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), file); no++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return no;
}


int main()
{
    char line[150][80];  
    char line2[150][80];  

    int i, j;

    FILE *file1 = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.csv", "r");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("file3.csv", "w");

   char fileOne[100]="file1.csv"; 
   int nolFileone = 0;
   nolFileone = numberOfLines(fileOne);


   char fileTwo[100]="file2.csv"; 
   int nolFiletwo = 0;
   nolFiletwo = numberOfLines(fileTwo);   

      for (i = 0; i < nolFileone; i++){
        fscanf(file1, "%79[^\n]\n", line[i]);

            for (j = 0; j < nolFiletwo-1; j++){
                fscanf(file2, "%79[^\n]\n", line2[j]);       
                if (strstr(line[i], line2[j]))
                fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line[i]);

            }
      }


    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```